# MS Teams - Someone in the meeting should let you in soon

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am creating an MS Teams meeting using Graph API

```
private string GetTeamsMeetingUrl()
{
    var appId = <<APP ID>>;
    var appSecret = <<APP SECRET >>;
    var tenantId = <<TENANT ID>>;
    var organizerId = <<ORGANIZER ID>>;

    IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(appId)
        .WithTenantId(tenantId)
        .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
        .Build();


    ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

    var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
    {
        Subject = "Meeting Title",
        Participants = new MeetingParticipants
        {
            Organizer = new MeetingParticipantInfo
            {
                Identity = new IdentitySet
                {
                    User = new Identity
                    {
                        Id = organizerId
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    };

    var onlineMeetingResponse = await graphClient.Communications.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
    return onlineMeetingResponse.JoinUrl;
}
```

And in `Microsoft Teams admin center`, I've set the policies as given below

```
Meetings - > Meeting policies - > Global(Org-wide default)
    Let anonymous people start a meeting - "ON"
    Automatically admit people - "Everyone"

Meetings - > Meeting setting
    Anonymous users can join a meeting - "ON"

Org-wide settings - > Guest access
    Allow guest access in Teams - "ON"
```

It was working as expected till last week.

Anonymous user and users of other organizations were able to join the meeting without "Admit" by organizer but all of sudden when anonymous user or user of another organization tries to join, we are getting "**Someone in the meeting should let you in soon**"

Kindly help if something else should also be configured.

Comment: Hi @Gopi, could you please go through the meeting polices in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/meeting-policies-in-teams). You will get complete idea on managing meeting policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also need to update the individual policy for the respective user in Microsoft Teams Center.

[image]